# how to work html video auto play with sound?

Tags: javascript, html

I added the html video code to the mute/unmute button. Here's my conflict, I tried to add my video to play automatically with the sound and someone muted the video to give some solution (when the sound is muted by clicking the mute button and the video should always be playing), but when is the play video sound Not playing automatically, then click the mute button Sound is playing, does anyone have a solution?

Thanks

here the code

```js
var video = document.getElementById("myVideo");
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

function myFunction() {
    btn.innerHTML = video.muted ? "Unmute":'Mute';
    video.muted = !video.muted;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">

  <button id="myBtn" onclick="myFunction()">Mute</button>
</div>

<video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

Comment: It's rather unclear what you are trying to do, but it seems like your problem could be solved by changing the initial innerHTML of your button to Unmute...

Comment: what does this mean? ... `not working correctly` ..... what is the current behavior?

Comment: @zevstravitz and jsotola , simply I'm tried to play my video auto-play with sound, some one want to muted the sound, just click the button and muted only sound, but my added code part its not working, it having some conflict its working the opposite this option, please check my video

Comment: @jsotola I updated my queation.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is closer to what you want? It also might help to add the controls attribute as this is generally better practice.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#attr-controls

```js
var video = document.getElementById("myVideo");
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

function myFunction() {
    video.muted = !video.muted;
    btn.innerHTML = video.muted ? "Unmute":'Mute';
}
```

```html
<video autoplay loop id="myVideo">
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>

<div class="content">

  <button id="myBtn" onclick="myFunction()">Toggle Mute</button>
</div>
```

Comment: hello there, I'm tried to play my video auto-play with sound, some one want to muted the sound, just click the button and muted only sound, but my added code part its not working, it having some conflict its working the opposite this option, please check my video